# How to make v-for drop-down text with a function?

Tags: vue.js, v-for, error-correction

I want to do a text-correction, where I can click the wrong words and choose a correction from the list(somewhat like Grammarly does).

This simple example should help you understand the idea. Let's assume I have a list of objects returned from a server:

```
data: {
 objects: [
  {
   word: "This",
   val:  0.1,
   corrections: {"that", "Those"}
  },
  {
   word: "kat",
   val:  0.9,
   corrections: {"cat", "cats", "dogs", "animals"}
  }
 ]
}
```

Now I want to write a v-for which will:

- Display all the words like if they were a regular text (eg. "This kat")
- For words with `val < 0.5` just display a `word`
- For words with `val >= 0.5` display a `word` with a red underline, and an ability to click and see a drop-down list with all `corrections`
- change the value of an object `word` after choosing an option in the drop-down.

**Minimal reproducible (not working) example:**

```js
Vue.component('post-list', {
  data: function() {
    return {
        objects: [{
            word: "This",
            val: 0.1,
            corrections: [
              "that",
              "Those"
            ]},
          {
            word: "kat",
            val: 0.9,
            corrections: [
              "cat",
              "cats",
              "dogs",
              "animals"
            ]}
        ]
    }
  },

});

new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app" class="container">
  <post-list inline-template>
    <div>
      <template class="post" v-for="object in objects">
        {{ object.word }}
      </template>
    </div>
  </post-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: yes, I will do that, thank you for your comment.

Comment: You're asking for quite a lot of technical implementation. You could probably make a new component or two for this specifically. I'd chop it up into a component that renders an overlay/wrapper (with red underline) that shows a menu when clicked, a component to check if your word should be wrapped with that component or a normal <span> (v-for this one), and maybe a separate one for handling the corrections menu as well.


PS: You'll probably want your corrections to be an Array instead of an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you are asking us to create a copy of "Grammarly" for you in like 10 minutes?

A'ight, challenge accepted. I've create a working but rough example to give you a starting point and perhaps some ideas on how to improve it. Keep in mind that it's not the best solution since I didn't put a lot of time and thought into it:

#### Demo https://codepen.io/aQW5z9fe/pen/MWaQjdX

Also, I would move the `getFormattedData()` method to the server, so that you get formatted data with `underlined` properties along with `val` and `corrections` instead of re-computing it on the client side.

```html
<v-menu 
  v-model="correctionsListIsVisible"
>
  <v-list dense>
    <v-list-item
      v-for="(correction, index) in correctionsListItems"
      :key="index"
      @click="applyCorrection(correction)"          
    >
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>
          {{correction}}
        </v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>

<div class="flex">
  <div v-for="(object, index) in getFormattedData" class="flex">
    <div
       @click="toggleCorrectionsList(object)"
       :class="{'underlined': object.underlined}"
       id="word"
    >{{ object.word }} 
    </div>
    <div v-if="addSpace(index)">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    correctionsListIsVisible: false,
    correctionsListItems: [],
    activeObject: {},
    objects: [
      {
         word: "This",
         val: 0.1,
         corrections: ["that", "Those"]
      },
      {
         word: "kat",
         val: 0.9,
         corrections: ["cat", "cats", "dogs", "animals"]
      },
      {
         word: "is",
         val: 0.1,
         corrections: []
      },
      {
         word: "cute",
         val: 0.2,
         corrections: []
      },
    ]
  }
},
computed: {
  getFormattedData() {
    let result = []
    for (const item of this.objects) {
      let object = {}
      if (item.val < 0.5) {
        object.word = item.word
        object.underlined = false
        object.corrections = []
      }
      else if (item.val >= 0.5) {
        object.word = item.word
        object.underlined = true
        object.corrections = item.corrections
      }

      result.push(object)
    }
    return result
  }
},
methods: {
  addSpace (index) {
    return index !== (this.getFormattedData.length - 1)
  },
  toggleCorrectionsList (object) {
    if (object.underlined) {
      this.correctionsListItems = object.corrections
      this.activeObject = object
      this.correctionsListIsVisible = true
    }
    else {
      this.activeObject = {}
    }
  },
  applyCorrection (correction) {
    this.activeObject.word = correction
    this.activeObject.underlined = false
  }
}
```